# ExpandableListView item color

Tags: android, android-layout

Looking for solution. I need change item color depend on text.
Below there is my fragment from ExpandableListAdapter. It works correctly but when I scroll up and down all item has the same color. Any solution for it?

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


 final ListItem childText = (ListItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    final TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setText(childText.getName());
    txtListChild.setTag(childText.getDocumentGuid());

    txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!txtListChild.getTag().equals("HEADER")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + txtListChild.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {
                    //header//

            }
        }
    });

    if(childText.getDocumentGuid().equals("HEADER")) {
        txtListChild.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_accent));
    }

    return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Correct me if I am Wrong, `ListView` is the predecessor of `RecyclerView` which also "Recycles" views that moved past the screen. So one thing you should add is `else` clause of your `if` :

```
if(childText.getDocumentGuid().equals("HEADER")) {
    txtListChild.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_accent));
} else {
txtListChild.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_something_else))
}
```